# Gstreamer plugins do not handle I420 format

Tags: video, encoding, streaming, gstreamer

I am using Gstreamer to stream a video file to `shmsink` and then out to network with `udpsink` but only does so if the caps-specified format when reading from `shmsrc` is `BGRA`.

Here are my pipelines:

```
sudo gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/home/me/files/Snowmix-0.5.1/test/big_buck_bunny_720p_H264_AAC_25fps_3400K.MP4 ! decodebin ! shmsink socket-path=/tmp/feed1-control-pipe shm-size=10000000 wait-for-connection=0
```

This pipeline reads the file specified and outputs it to a shared memory sink.

```
sudo GST_DEBUG=mpegtsmux:5 gst-launch-1.0 shmsrc socket-path=/tmp/feed1-control-pipe do-timestamp=true is-live=true ! 'video/x-raw, format=I420, max-input-size=200000, width=320, height=720, framerate=25/1' ! videoconvert ! x264enc !  mpegtsmux ! udpsink host=192.168.78.10 port=4012 sync=true
```

This pipeline read from the shared memory source and attempts to output via UDP. In the above pipeline we can see that I have specified the format of the video to be `I420` which is indeed the encoding of the video file. However, it seems that there is zero interaction at the `mpegtsmux` plugin which should reformat the stream as an `mpeg` transport stream.

Changing the format from `I420` to `BGRA` even though the file itself is encoded as `I420` then allows us to see interaction at the `mpegtsmux` plugin. The video is output and can be played back on VLC but the formatting is clearly wrong and plays oddly.

Note: The pipeline above specifies a resolution of `width=320` and `height=720` because increasing it to the normal `width=1280` and `height=720` with `BGRA` causes the following error:

```
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0: Internal GStreamer error: code not implemented.  Please file a bug at http://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=GStreamer.
Additional debug info:
gstvideofilter.c(292): gst_video_filter_transform (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0:
invalid video buffer received
```

Using the normal resolution with `I420` does not produce the above error but again does not pass the stream past the `mpegtsmux` plugin in the pipeline.

Why is it that streams identified as `I420` when reading from the `shmsrc` do not pass through my pipeline successfully? Is there a compatibility issue with `x264enc` or `videoconvert` and `I420`?

Answer (score 0):

Querying the component `shmsrc` with `gst-inspect-1.0 shmsrc` returns:

```
Pad Templates:
  SRC template: 'src'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      ANY
```

Suggessing that it is capable of receiving any format including `I420`. We also know that `videoconvert` supports input of `I420`. For this reason I think that your stream is formatted `RGBA`. If the file is formatted `I420` probably `decodebin` element converts it to `RGBA`.